# How to write own php template engine?

Tags: php, template-engine

I want to write my own template engine within another plugins similar to smarty.

```
<body>
<p><?php echo $paragraph; ?></p>
<i><?php echo date("l"); ?></i>
</body>
```

But I want to write as below

```
<body>
<p>{paragraph}</p>
<i>{day}</i>
</body>
```

How can i write engine as upper.

Comment: PHP itself is kind of a templating language. Why add an unnecessary layer over it? Moreover, there are dozens of existing template engines that you may be able to adapt. Anyway, an here's an old tutorial that may help - http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Display-Tutorials/Writing-a-Template-System-in-PHP/

Comment: But why do you want to invent the wheel again? But the normal way is to replace the strings. Look at Smarty how they does it ;)

Comment: If you want to re-write Smarty, you might want to take a look at its source code.

Comment: I want to know logic of smarty or other template engines..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, you are looking for something along the lines of the following:

```
php > $t = "Hello {name}";
php > $v = "name";
php > $name = "Test";
php > echo str_replace('{'. $v .'}', $$v, $t);
Hello Test
```